# Creating a queue with structs in C

Tags: c

I have a code (at the end of this post) that implements a circular queue system. Everything works perfectly, but as can be seen in the function `createQueue` the queue is implemented only for integers. I would like to modify this code to accept a struct informed by the user.

I could create a known struct and replace all sites with integer, but this way I would be coupling the code to a known struct. Bad idea...

How could pass to the function `createQueue` a struct for memory allocation without needing to know the struct previously? The struct Queue should also be changed, in **int *elements** the value should be changed from integer to void?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Queue
{
        int capacity;
        int size;
        int front;
        int rear;
        int *elements;
}Queue;

Queue * createQueue(int maxElements)
{
        /* Create a Queue */
        Queue *Q;
        Q = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
        /* Initialise its properties */
        Q->elements = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*maxElements);
        Q->size = 0;
        Q->capacity = maxElements;
        Q->front = 0;
        Q->rear = -1;
        /* Return the pointer */
        return Q;
}
void Dequeue(Queue *Q)
{
        /* If Queue size is zero then it is empty. So we cannot pop */
        if(Q->size==0)
        {
                printf("Queue is Empty\n");
                return;
        }
        /* Removing an element is equivalent to incrementing index of front by one */
        else
        {
                Q->size--;
                Q->front++;
                /* As we fill elements in circular fashion */
                if(Q->front==Q->capacity)
                {
                        Q->front=0;
                }
        }
        return;
}
int front(Queue *Q)
{
        if(Q->size==0)
        {
                printf("Queue is Empty\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        /* Return the element which is at the front*/
        return Q->elements[Q->front];
}
void Enqueue(Queue *Q,int element)
{
        /* If the Queue is full, we cannot push an element into it as there is no space for it.*/
        if(Q->size == Q->capacity)
        {
                printf("Queue is Full\n");
        }
        else
        {
                Q->size++;
                Q->rear = Q->rear + 1;
                /* As we fill the queue in circular fashion */
                if(Q->rear == Q->capacity)
                {
                        Q->rear = 0;
                }
                /* Insert the element in its rear side */ 
                Q->elements[Q->rear] = element;
        }
        return;
}
int main()
{
        Queue *Q = createQueue(5);
        Enqueue(Q,1);
        Enqueue(Q,2);
        Enqueue(Q,3);
        Enqueue(Q,4);
        printf("Front element is %d\n",front(Q));
        Enqueue(Q,5);
        Dequeue(Q);
        Enqueue(Q,6);
        printf("Front element is %d\n",front(Q));
}
```

Comment: you would be better off with C++ and templates... Is C++ ruled out?

Comment: Easiest (in C) would probably be to change the queue's element type from `int` to `void *`.  You could then store pointers to structs in it, or equally well store pointers to any other type of data.

Comment: in that case, bye bye to `int front(Queue *Q)` function.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, there's no reason why `front()` could not be modified for a different element type.  It returns the element at the front of the queue, so its type would need to be changed in conjunction with the element type change, but there's no reason why that could not be done.

Comment: _"How could pass to the function createQueue a struct for memory allocation without needing to know the struct previously?"_ add one more parameter to this function - size of the struct. Than all other code will have to use `memcpy` probably to enqueue/dequie structs passed/retrieved using pointers. This is 2nd option, is 1st one offered by @JohnBollinger is not acceptable (for example if queue is the only container of those structs and you cannot keep them outside)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How much *pain* do you enjoy?

Jean-François Fabre's method is a good one, and is a fair approximation of using C++ templates.  I have another one that avoids using the preprocessor, but it's a *lot* more work, and is a poor-to-middling approximation of subclassing.  I prefer this method to the preprocessor approach, though, mainly because I'm brain-damaged.

We start with your basic `Queue` type, but instead of storing an array of `int`, store an array of `void *`:

```
typedef struct Queue
{
        int capacity;
        int size;
        int front;
        int rear;
        void **elements; 
        ...
}Queue;
```

meaning that your `Enqueue` prototype is going to look like

```
void Enqueue( Queue *Q, void *element )
```

Now, as soon as we use `void *`, we have ***problems*** - we've thrown type safety out the window, *and* we don't really know what the pointed-to data is supposed to look like.  Secondly, we have to create a *copy* of whatever input data we get (we can't just write `element` to the `elements` list).  We also can't use a `void *` to store scalars like `int` or `float` values.  So we need to add at least the following type-aware helper functions:

- `copy` - allocates and assigns a copy of the input to Enqueue
- `destroy` - destroys an object removed from the queue

So we add these functions to our `Queue` type as follows:

```
typedef struct Queue
{
        int capacity;
        int size;
        int front;
        int rear;
        void *elements;
        void *(*copy)(const void *);
        void (*destroy)(const void *);
}Queue;
```

So, let's say we want to create a queue to store `float`s.  We create the following helper functions:

```
void *copyFloat( const void *f )
{
  float *p = malloc( sizeof *p );
  if ( p )
  {
    *p = *(float *) f;
  }
  return p;
}

void destroyFloat( const void *f )
{
  free( f );
}
```

and then create a new `Queue` object that uses them:

```
Queue * createQueue(int maxElements, 
                    void *(*copy)(const void *), 
                    void (*destroy)(const void *),
{
  /* Create a Queue */
  Queue *Q;
  Q = malloc( sizeof *Q );
  /* Initialise its properties */
  Q->elements = malloc(sizeof *Q->elements * maxElements);
  Q->size = 0;
  Q->capacity = maxElements;
  Q->front = 0;
  Q->rear = -1;

  Q->copy = copy;
  Q->destroy = destroy;

  /* Return the pointer */
  return Q;
}
...
Queue *floatQueue = CreateQueue( 100, copyFloat, destroyFloat );
```

Your `Enqueue` function now looks like

```
void Enqueue(Queue *Q, void *element)
{
  /* If the Queue is full, we cannot push an element into it as there is no space for it.*/
  if(Q->size == Q->capacity)
  {
    printf("Queue is Full\n");
  }
  else
  {
    Q->size++;
    Q->rear = Q->rear + 1;
    /* As we fill the queue in circular fashion */
    if(Q->rear == Q->capacity)
    {
      Q->rear = 0;
    }
    /* Insert the element in its rear side */ 
    Q->elements[Q->rear] = Q->copy( element ); // <--- create a copy of the input
  }
  return;
}
```

Why do we need to create the copy?  Imagine if you called `Enqueue` like the following:

```
float f;
...
f = get_new_value();
Enqueue( &queue, &f );
```

If we just copied the input parameter `element` to the queue, we'd be writing the same address to every element of the queue - the address of the variable `f`.  Thus, every element of the queue would be pointing to the same (invalid) thing.

Conversely, when we dequeue an object, we now have to make sure we clean up that memory:

```
void Dequeue(Queue *Q)
{
  /* If Queue size is zero then it is empty. So we cannot pop */
  if(Q->size==0)
  {
    printf("Queue is Empty\n");
    return;
  }
  /* Removing an element is equivalent to incrementing index of front by one */
  else
  {
    Q->destroy( Q->elements[Q->front] ); // deallocate the dequeued object
    Q->size--;
    Q->front++;
    /* As we fill elements in circular fashion */
    if(Q->front==Q->capacity)
    {
      Q->front=0;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

And your `front` function now returns a `void *`:

```
void *front(Queue *Q)
{
  if(Q->size==0)
  {
    printf("Queue is Empty\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  /* Return the element which is at the front*/
  return Q->elements[Q->front];
}
```

We're not done yet - to make this work, we *still* need a type-aware front end:

```
void EnqueueFloat( Queue *floatQueue, float f )
{
  Enqueue( floatQueue, &f );
}

float frontFloat( Queue *floatQueue )
{
  float *p = front( floatQueue );
  return *p;
}
```

What a mess.

But...

Once you have the basic queue mechanics in place, all you need to do is implement new `copy` and `destroy` functions for each new type you want to use, along with a new type-aware front end.  You don't have to create a whole new `Queue_XXX` data type for each data type, nor to you need to create whole new copies of `Enqueue_XXX` and `front_XXX` and `Dequeue_XXX`; you only need to implement a thin, type-aware wrapper for each.

There are doubtless many ways to improve what I've written; there are ways to avoid allocating a deallocating a copy for every input, but then indexing into the queue becomes a little less clean.

Anyway, it's just food for thought.

Answer (score 9):

Even if you aren't good friends with C++, you can create a pseudo-template:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define QUEUE_TEMPLATE(ELTTYPE) \
typedef struct \
{\
        int capacity;\
        int size;\
        int front;\
        int rear;\
        ELTTYPE *elements;\
}Queue_##ELTTYPE;\
\
Queue_##ELTTYPE * createQueue_##ELTTYPE(int maxElements)\
{\
        /* Create a Queue */\
        Queue_##ELTTYPE *Q;\
        Q = (Queue_##ELTTYPE *)malloc(sizeof(Queue_##ELTTYPE));\
        /* Initialise its properties */\
        Q->elements = malloc(sizeof(ELTTYPE)*maxElements);\
        Q->size = 0;\
        Q->capacity = maxElements;\
        Q->front = 0;\
        Q->rear = -1;\
        /* Return the pointer */\
        return Q;\
}\
void Dequeue_##ELTTYPE(Queue_##ELTTYPE *Q)\
{\
        /* If Queue size is zero then it is empty. So we cannot pop */\
        if(Q->size==0)\
        {\
                printf("Queue is Empty\n");\
                return;\
        }\
        /* Removing an element is equivalent to incrementing index of front by one */\
        else\
        {\
                Q->size--;\
                Q->front++;\
                /* As we fill elements in circular fashion */\
                if(Q->front==Q->capacity)\
                {\
                        Q->front=0;\
                }\
        }\
        return;\
}\
ELTTYPE front_##ELTTYPE(Queue_##ELTTYPE *Q)\
{\
        if(Q->size==0)\
        {\
                printf("Queue is Empty\n");\
                exit(0);\
        }\
        /* Return the element which is at the front*/\
        return Q->elements[Q->front];\
}\
void Enqueue_##ELTTYPE(Queue_##ELTTYPE *Q,ELTTYPE element)\
{\
        /* If the Queue is full, we cannot push an element into it as there is no space for it.*/\
        if(Q->size == Q->capacity)\
        {\
                printf("Queue is Full\n");\
        }\
        else\
        {\
                Q->size++;\
                Q->rear++;\
                /* As we fill the queue in circular fashion */\
                if(Q->rear == Q->capacity)\
                {\
                        Q->rear = 0;\
                }\
                /* Insert the element in its rear side */ \
                Q->elements[Q->rear] = element;\
        }\
        return;\
}

QUEUE_TEMPLATE(int);
QUEUE_TEMPLATE(float);

int main()
{
        Queue_int *Q = createQueue_int(5);
        Queue_float *QF = createQueue_float(5);
        Enqueue_int(Q,1);
        Enqueue_int(Q,2);
        Enqueue_int(Q,3);
        Enqueue_int(Q,4);
        printf("Front element is %d\n",front_int(Q));
        Enqueue_int(Q,5);
        Dequeue_int(Q);
        Enqueue_int(Q,6);
        printf("Front element is %d\n",front_int(Q));

        Enqueue_float(QF,1);
        Enqueue_float(QF,2);
        Enqueue_float(QF,3);
        Enqueue_float(QF,4);
        printf("Front element is %f\n",front_float(QF));
        Enqueue_float(QF,5);
        Dequeue_float(QF);
        Enqueue_float(QF,6);
        printf("Front element is %f\n",front_float(QF));
}
```

I have added 2 instanciations with 2 different types. Output is:

```
Front element is 1
Front element is 2
Front element is 1.000000
Front element is 2.000000
```

*Drawback of this method*: compilation errors on the macro code may be painful to track down.
You could create the code with a known type, debug/improve it, and then use a `sed` filter to generate the macro code, replacing the type by `ELTTYPE` and adding the `#define` and the trailing backslashes